# MVC Passing Four Pieces of Data to the Controller and subsequently to the View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, tuples

This question is part B of my other question here:

[Inefficient MVC ViewModel Making Multiple Calls to the Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17318954/inefficient-mvc-viewmodel-making-multiple-calls-to-the-database)

I knew multiple calls to the db was a bad idea.  But, I guess my real question is if I use my last chunk of code or speti43's example let's say like this in my model constructor to eliminate multiple db calls:

```
    Public Class OrdersSummary{
    ...
      Public ???? GetOrders(){

        var ordersInMemory = orders.ToList();
        decimal? GrossProfitTotal = ordersInMemory.Sum(s => s.Profit);
        decimal? CommissionTotal = ordersInMemory.Sum(s => s.Commission);
        decimal? NetProfitTotal = GrossProfitTotal + CommissionTotal;
        return ?????

      }
    }
```

How do I pass those seperate but similar pieces of data to the controller?  I was trying to use a tuple like this based on some other SO article recommendation here:

[How to return multiple values from a function in C# (ASP.NET)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845831/how-to-return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-c-sharp-asp-net)

```
public Tuple<IEnumerable<dynamic>, decimal?, decimal?, decimal?> GetOrders(string sortOrder, string searchString)
{
...

    return new Tuple<IEnumerable<dynamic>,decimal?,decimal?,decimal?> (ordersInMemory, GrossProfitTotal, CommissionTotal, NetProfitTotal);
}
```

Does this sound reasonable?  Then I have no idea how to reference the tuple in my controller:

```
        var ordersummary = new OrdersSummary();
        var viewModel = new OrderSummary
        {
            ???? cause I have no idea how to reference the tuple
        };
        return View(viewModel);
```

The other issue is I'm not entirely sure I'm building the properties correct in my view model. Currently I have it like this for the four pieces of data and then individual properties of the Orders list:

```
public class OrderSummary
    {
        public IEnumerable<dynamic> Orders { get; set; }
        public decimal GrossProfitTotal { get; set; }
        public decimal CommissionTotal { get; set; }
        public decimal NetProfitTotal { get; set; }

        //Orders Table Properties
        public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime OpenTime { get; set; }
        //more properties here that correspond to the Orders table.
    }
```

It seems like I might need to structure the tuple properties different in the view model?  If so, what syntax?

I think I might know what goes in the View if I knew what goes in the controller.  Is this even the correct way to go about it?  I got this whole view model structure idea from step 8 on the MVCMUsicStore tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much cursing and even more red squiggly lines, I figured out a couple ways to do this and neither involves a tuple:

**First Method:**

ViewModel:

```
public IEnumerable<OrderSummary> Orders { get; set; }
public decimal? GrossProfitTotal { get { return Orders.Sum(s => (decimal)s.Profit); } }
public decimal? CommissionTotal { get { return Orders.Sum(s => (decimal)s.Commission); } }
public decimal? NetProfitTotal { get { return GrossProfitTotal + CommissionTotal; } }
```

Controller:

```
var orderssummary = new OrdersSummary();
var viewModel = new OrderSummary
{
   Orders = orderssummary.GetOrders(sortOrder, searchString),
}

return View(viewModel);
```

**Second Method:**

ViewModel:

```
public IEnumerable<OrderSummary> Orders { get; set; }        
public decimal? GrossProfitTotal { get; set; }
public decimal? CommissionTotal { get; set; }
public decimal? NetProfitTotal { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
    var orderssummary = new OrdersSummary();
    var orderslist = orderssummary.GetOrders(sortOrder, searchString);

    decimal? grossprofittotal = orderslist.Sum(s => (decimal)s.Profit);
    decimal? commissiontotal = orderslist.Sum(s => (decimal)s.Commission);
    decimal? netprofittotal = orderslist.Sum(s => (decimal)s.Profit + s.Commission);

        var viewModel = new OrderSummary
        {
            Orders = orderslist,
            GrossProfitTotal = grossprofittotal,
            CommissionTotal = commissiontotal,
            NetProfitTotal = netprofittotal,
        };

    return View(viewModel);
```

**View (for first and second methods):**

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Orders){
   @item.OrderNumber
   @item.OpenTime
   etc.
}
    @Model.CommissionTotal
    @Model.GrossProfitTotal
    @Model.NetProfitTotal
```

I am currently using number 1 as it appears a little cleaner.  I believe it is now looping through my Ienumerable for the other values instead of hitting the db for each one?  I would love to figure out how to calculate all values on a single loop.

It also appears I don't even really need a viewmodel for number 1, but I'll be adding other pieces of info to the view like chart data, so I will leave my options open.

I'm always interested to know people's thoughts and if they have a preference for either or a whole better way.